# Как добавить роль без снятия конфигурации с поддержки 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть роль на изменение таблицы, я хочу добавить такую же роль, но только на чтение. Проблема в том, что конфигурация закрыта для изменений. Я знаю как ее открыть, но можно ли как-то добавить роль без снятия конфигурации с поддержки?

Возможно ли это сделать через расширения конфигурации? Не совсем понял, там создается копия роли, у которой можно изменить права, или изменяется выбранная. Если второй вариант, то, видимо, вариант через расширения не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Книга "[Расширения конфигураций. Как адаптировать прикладные решения при внедрении. Разработка в системе 1С:Предприятие 8.3. Издание 2](https://its.1c.ru/db/pubextensions#content:66:hdoc)"

Глава 2. Функциональность - Роли